# /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* links pointing to sdX instead of multipath device

Tags: linux, multipath, sles10

We have two similar SLES10SP2 servers both using multipath on the same devices
from the same storage array.

On one server, the /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* devices properly point at the
multipath devices:

```
server1:/dev/disk/by-id # ls -l scsi-* | awk '{print $9,$10,$11;}'
scsi-3600a0b80005047d80000050c4933f22c -> ../../dm-1
scsi-3600a0b80005047d80000050c4933f22c-part1 -> ../../dm-2
scsi-3600a0b80005047d80000050c4933f22c-part2 -> ../../dm-3
scsi-3600a0b80005047d80000b0a14dbb20e4 -> ../../dm-0
```

On the other, the /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* disk devices are pointing at one of
the paths instead of the multipath dm device:

```
server2:/dev/disk/by-id # ls -l scsi-* | awk '{print $9,$10,$11;}'
scsi-3600a0b80005047d80000a3464a07f6ee -> ../../dm-1
scsi-3600a0b8000505008000004f84933e183 -> ../../sda
scsi-3600a0b8000505008000004f84933e183-part1 -> ../../dm-4
scsi-3600a0b8000505008000004f84933e183-part2 -> ../../dm-5
scsi-3600a0b80005050080000057749352a81 -> ../../sdd
scsi-3600a0b80005050080000057749352a81-part1 -> ../../dm-6
scsi-3600a0b80005050080000a7cd4dbb2498 -> ../../sdg
```

This causes a problem as some of the disks are configured to use the entire
disk as a pv.

What do we need to change on server2 to have the system set up all of the scsi-* links to
point to the multipath devices instead of a single path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a known issue in SLES10SP2.

It's fixed in SLES10SP3 with package `udev-085-30.58.3.6.x86_64.rpm`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.novell.com/documentation/sles11/stor_admin/?page=/documentation/sles11/stor_admin/data/be5rvii.html):

> In SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10,
>   the kpartx software is used in the
>   /etc/init.d/boot.multipath to add
>   symlinks to the /dev/dm-* line in the
>   multipath.conf configuration file for
>   any newly created partitions without
>   requiring a reboot. This triggers
>   udevd to fill in the /dev/disk/by-*
>   symlinks.

So, I would

1. Check whether boot.multipath was run on the second server
2. Check that udev is configured identically on both servers
3. Check that *udevd* is running on the second server

If all of that is true, you could try running `kpartx -a` on the multipath devices to see if the entries in */dev/disk/by-id/* are updated.

After you straighten this out, you still need to edit lvm.conf. Again, from the [documentation](http://www.novell.com/documentation/sles11/stor_admin/?page=/documentation/sles11/stor_admin/data/be5rvii.html):

> By default, LVM2 does not recognize multipathed devices. To make LVM2 recognize the multipathed devices as possible physical volumes, you must modify /etc/lvm/lvm.conf. It is important to modify it so that it does not scan and use the physical paths, but only accesses the multipath I/O storage through the multipath I/O layer. If you are using user-friendly names, make sure to specify the path so that it scans only the device mapper names for the device (/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-.*-mpath-.*) after multipathing is configured.

Comment: All of these good ideas - however not applicable in my case. Already been done. Awarding you the bounty as it does make a good reference for people to check.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a filter rule in `lvm.conf`

```
filter =[ "a|/dev/dm|", "a|^/dev/sda2$|", "r|/dev/sd|"]
```

In this example, lvm uses all /dev/md* /dev/sda2 and removes all other /dev/sd* devices.

Comment: Presumably you mean /dev/dm... yes it's a workaround for this specific case, but doesn't actually fix the problem.